# C# - Specify a struct field type from a generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, struct

In C#, is it possible to create a struct that does something like this?

I'm trying to vary the field size inside PrimeStruct without declaring _myField as an interface, just deferring from closing the IData declaration until the PrimeStruct is created.

I know WHY this doesn't work, but trying to find if someone has syntactic sugar for deferring type declaration of the contents of PrimeStruct to a contained generic type.

(Like `PrimeStruct<T>`)

**(no surprise: this does not compile)**

```
interface IBehavior { void Foo(); }

interface IData<T> where T : IBehavior { }

struct MyStruct1 : IBehavior
{
    public void Foo() { }
}

struct MyStruct2 : IBehavior
{
    public void Foo() { }
}

       //specifying an open type <T> here doesn't compile
public struct PrimeStruct : IData<T>, IBehavior
{
    T _myField;

    internal void SetData<T>(T value) where T : IBehavior
    {
        _myField = value;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _myField.Foo();
    }
}

public class Runner
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrimeStruct p = new PrimeStruct();
        p.SetData(new MyStruct1());
        p.Foo();
    }
}
```

Or does this fall under the umbrella of the type not being known at compile time?  I'm trying to avoid boxing the _myField struct value to an interface or resorting to HAllocGlobal.

Answer (score 1):

`PrimeStruct` also needs a generic parameter for this to work.

```
public struct PrimeStruct<T> : IData<T>, IBehavior
```

Comment: Yes, and I was trying to avoid specifying that :-)

Comment: Then the answer is just "no, you can't".

Answer (score 1):

Since `IData<T>` has no members, it's unclear what you're wanting the generic parameter for.  If the intention is that `IData<T>` should constrain `T` to `IBehavior`, and provide a means of getting and setting it, I would suggest that you have `IData<T>` inherit from a non-generic `IData` with a member of type `IBehavior`; that method may provide a property getter, and a method to set the property, but the documentation for the method should make clear that most implementations of non-generic `IData` will only accept certain implementations of `IBehavior`.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. In reality IData<T> has members, but it exists just to demonstrate the concept here. I am trying to defer declaring the type of _myField, so the client only interacts with PrimeStruct and the fields of T it exposes. Normally you would do this with interfaces but then incur boxing. In C, you could malloc your way to victory :-)

Comment: @WolfOdrade: Suppose you try to create an array of `PrimeStruct`.  The array will only have one piece of type information, which must define the type of `_myField` for every element thereof.  If one wishes to store different kinds of thing into the `_myField` of each element, then each thing must have type information for it stored somewhere; that would in turn imply that they must be heap objects--either class-type instances or boxed structures.

Comment: That's what I thought, but was hoping there was some magic I didn't know about for deferring declaration of a generic type inside a non-generic type. Once it's actually created, it doesn't need to change. Doesn't sound like it though.

Comment: @WolfOdrade: Something has to know the generic type.  You could have a generic class inherit from a non-generic class which includes abstract methods to act upon a collection of members defined in the generic class; if all collections will be homogenous, that would let you avoid per-item boxing without consumers of the class having to know the item type, but the type would have to be known when the concrete generic-class object is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Like supercat said, it is not clear from this code what `IData<T>` is for.  If you take out the requirement that `PrimeStruct` implement `IData<T>`, and change _myField to an `IBehavior`, then this will compile.

```
interface IBehavior { void Foo(); }

interface IData<T> where T : IBehavior { }

struct MyStruct1 : IBehavior
{
    public void Foo() { }
}

struct MyStruct2 : IBehavior
{
    public void Foo() { }
}

//specifying an open type <T> here doesn't compile
public struct PrimeStruct : IBehavior
{
    IBehavior _myField;

    internal void SetData<T>(T value) where T : IBehavior
    {
        _myField = value;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _myField.Foo();
    }
}

public class Runner
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrimeStruct p = new PrimeStruct();
        p.SetData(new MyStruct1());
        p.Foo();
    }
}
```

As Preston Guillot said, you cannot have an non-generic class that inherits from an open generic (i.e. `IData<T>`).

```
 PrimeStruct : IData<int> // Non-generic inherits from closed generic is OK
 PrimeStruct<T> : IData<T> // Open generic inherits from open generic is OK
 PrimeStruct : IData<T> // Non-generic inherits from open generic will not compile
```

Comment: The point is to Avoid Boxing something that implements IBehavior inside PrimeStruct. I went into this question expecting that this probably wasn't possible, but wanted to make sure before implementing Plan B. Also IData has no members for demonstration purposes but in reality it does and is also named differently :-). It exists just to demonstrate the concept.